# Is GraphQL overkill for my node express backend

Tags: api, rest, graphql, microservices, apollo-client

I have a PostgreSQL database with various relationships between different entities/tables. E.g. teachers and students, teachers and classrooms, students and classes. In my (express) backend*, I find myself writing a lot of tedious routes to extract data - the routes make similar but slightly different SQL queries (we use sequelize), e.g.

- get students based on age
- get teachers based on school
- get all students that learn with particular teacher(s)
- get all teachers that teach particular student(s)
- get all students that went to a class between certain times
- get all students that went to a class between certain times and had certain teacher(s).

granted, the last 2 could be merged into one REST endpoint easily by passing null for a when no teachers constraint. Still, there are many many more permutations and that number is only growing with new entities.

To speed up development, I am wondering if (i) GraphQL would buy us anything (we have ~30 routes today) (ii) if it is even possible to setup and use GraphQL to *somehow* connect to my postgreSQL (and redis) database without doing a LOT of boiler plate work.

I have had a look through the Apollo docs (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/data-source/), and looking at SQLDataSource (https://github.com/cvburgess/SQLDataSource), it seems that I still need to write/expose endpoints for every one of my scenarios - e.g. if i want to find which students have which teachers I still need to write a manual SQL query to do that and expose that as a method on a SQLDataSource object. I presume I am misunderstanding something here as I thought this was a key value proposition of GraphQL.

Thank you so much!

*we just have 1 service today but are adding another shortly

Answer (score 0):

Based of you requirements, I only see three endpoints, one with few query params but nothing so complex, as example:

```
GET /students
GET /students?birthdate=<birthdate_year>
GET /students/<student_id>/teachers
GET /students?class_dtstart=<dtstart>&class_dtend=<dtend>
GET /students?class_dtstart=<dtstart>&class_dtend=<dtend>&teacher_id=<teacher_id>

GET /schools/<school_id>/students

GET /teachers/<teacher_id>/students
```

I think that you can play to few endpoints with some params to build the query that you want in a clasic rest api schema. Obviously you need to write somo code to transform que route params to your SQL query but I think it is not very complex.